# Cannot figure out why vc-git.elc is always loaded on startup

Tags: init-file, git, start-up, vc, load-path

This is more a curiosity, than a necessity.

I'm playing around with startup times, and to have something to compare with, I wanted to see how fast emacs could start up pure.

Running `emacs -Q`, `emacs-init-time` reported 0.3~ secs on average.

With a blank config, I installed [esup (Emacs Start Up Profiler)](https://github.com/jschaf/esup), and the `init.el` file became:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/esup-0.7")
(require 'esup)
```

To test it out, I launched emacs normally, and ran `esup`.

[image: result of running the esup command]

Huh, look that. `vc-git` is loaded.

Curious on how low the start up time can get, I try to disable it.

And so it begins.

> To disable VC entirely, set the customizable variable vc-handled-backends to nil
> https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html

I insert `(setq-default vc-handled-backends nil)` into `init.el`

Still being loaded.

Perhaps removing the vc entry it from `load-path` does the trick.

So I also add `(delete "/usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp/vc" load-path)` to the config.

Still being loaded. Challenge accepted.

I try to add `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/overwrites")` to the newly supported `early-init.el` config file, and add a dummy `vc-git.el` file into the folder specified, containing just `(provide 'vc-git)`

Still being loaded. Same if I move the line from `early-init.el` to `init.el`.

No effect by adding `(setq-default load-suffixes '(".el"))` either.

Seeing no other way to prevent it from loading, I try the nuclear option of moving the offending file `/usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp/vc/vc-git.elc` temporarily.

Finally it does not load.

So it is possible.

Now I'm just wondering if it is possible without going nuclear.

For science (and negible reduced startup time)

Comment: Use `after-load-functions` to call `debug` -- or just throw `(debug)` into `vc-git.el` and re-compile -- and you should learn what's causing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it out after the weekend.

Comment: Interesting. I'm getting somewhere... 
https://github.com/jschaf/esup/issues/51#issuecomment-386924846